# IPython notebook hanging

Tags: numpy, ipython

I am struggling with making [this iPython notebook](https://github.com/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-2-Numpy.ipynb) run.

When I run it using:

```
ipython notebook
```

and then on my browser, when I click on the notebook, I get a Firefox pop up saying "Unresponsive Script". I am not able to run any cell.

All other notebooks are running fine in [the repository](https://github.com/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures). I thought it's problem with my system, but I have tried running in my friend's system and it doesn't work there too.

What do I do?

Everything seems fine with the code. How do I at least come to know what's causing the problem. All I have is a script unresponsive!

Comment: works here. What version of jupyter/ipython are you using, how did you install, what OS?

Comment: I installed using anaconda 64-bit on linux. Ipython version is 4 and OS is Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: I don't know but it's working now. I gave it a minute or two and it's running fine.